# How to alias yafc as sftp on macosx

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, bash

I tried this and it doesnt work:

`alias sftp='yafc sftp://'`

I would like to be able to use the shorter sftp syntax from the command line.  For example:

`sftp bob@ibm.com`

rather than having to type this each time

`yafc sftp://bob@ibm.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really need is bash function:

```
sftp(){
    yafc sftp://"$@"
}
```

BAD work-around:
But if you are keen on using `alias` & you have password-less authentication enabled, thus not requiring anything to be entered on stdin, then this hacky method will work too (bash 4+):

```
alias sftp='(read IP; yafc sftp://"$IP";) <<< '
```

Comment: Note: I had to add the word function before sftp() for it to work